# Multiple CALayer instances created by a UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, calayer

I'm working on a project where I'm using a `CAShapeLayer` to render a grid behind some content. The problem is that **the OS creates multiple instances of this `CAShapeLayer` subclass, when I'm expecting one**.

First, I subclassed `CAShapeLayer`, overriding `init` and `layoutSublayers` (the layer has a few sublayers that render additional content).

Then, I overrode `+[UIView layerClass]` in the view that uses my `CAShapeLayer` subclass.

Lastly, the view using my layer was added as a subview to a `UIScrollView`.

To reference self.layer (in the view) with the correct class (`GridLayer` vs `CALayer`), I created the following property:

`@property (nonatomic, weak, readonly, getter=graphLayer) GraphLayer *graphLayer;`

and getter

```
- (GraphLayer *)graphLayer {
    return (GraphLayer *)self.layer;
}
```